# Youtube API: query not returning all expected results

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to return all videos with the word "second" in their title or description.

Here are the 4 most recent published videos on the channel:

```
Sausage Party - Official 12 Second Trailer HD
Ben Hur - Official 12 Second Trailer HD 
Criminal - Official 12 Second Trailer HD
Central Intelligence - Official 12 Second Trailer HD
```

When I make the query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=second&type=video&channelId=XXXXXX&maxResults=50&key=XXXXXX
```

The first two videos show up, but the second two do not. Even though the search term is clearly in the title of the video.

Any ideas why those movies aren't being returned?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add &order=date